# How to pull up the selected edge and scale to the center at the same time?

Tags: modeling

in [this video](https://www.instagram.com/reel/COQozLEA8w-/?igshid=3qozta3ud9tl), after putting 3 loop cuts and making them wider and then deleting their faces, he/she will select the topper edge of each part, and pull it up and scale towards center so that the edge will go under the upper surface all at the same time. I mean the part of the video which some yellow lines appear. I wanna know how he/she will pull up the edge and scale it to the center at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Whatever the exact moves are, after V ripping the edges to make separate face-pair tiles, the transforms are based on the Pivot being 'individual Origins',  and the Orientation being 'Normal'. Maybe a bit of Alt-GG, unclamped edge-slide.

Comment: @RobinBetts It didn't work.

Comment: It turns out to be the GG bit, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stand corrected on my comment, the 'Normal' orientation is not needed here, (although the combination of 'Individual Origins' and the 'Normal' orientation is very handy in situations like this.)

With Pivot set to 'Individual Origins', amd Orientation left at 'Global':

Having <kbd>Alt</kbd> selected the horizontal edge loops, and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> from initial pairs to select every other cut between tiles, they are <kbd>V</kbd> ripped to separate the faces.

Then in Face mode, all faces are <kbd>S</kbd> scaled down a bit to make selection of tile bottom-edges a bit easier. With that Edge mode selection, and the cursor near the middle of the view...

[image]

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> raise the bottom edges to tilt the tiles without splaying their bottom corners, and then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide, with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held to release the clamp.

The tiles can be scaled back again if you want to reduce the cracks between them. Various tile-bottoms are moved up and down a bit, using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> again, for a chirpy randomness. Maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelling the corner-vertices makes the tiles a bit cuter.

After *Solidify*, *Bevel* (by angle) and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers..

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It helped.